# If 204 No Content is displayed, how should the Javascript map function be handled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want `oneToOneInquery` to display `<p>null</p>` if length is less than 0 and call Row function if length is 1 or more.

```
              {oneToOneInquery?.map((value : OneToOneInfo) => {
                        return oneToOneInquery.length < 0 ?
                            <p>null</p> : 
                            <Row 
                            key={value.id}
                            value={value}
                            />
                           })}
```

But oneToOneInquery did not receive the array itself from the API, but received the API with 204 No COntent and did not receive any data.
In this case, how should we deal with it?